# Where in a smartphone with Android are deleted and cleaned the files that are visible when testing with "root integrity check"?

Tags: applications, adb, windows, motorola, adblock-plus

Where in a smartphone with Android are deleted and cleaned the files that are visible when testing with "root integrity check" ?? Clearing the cache and user settings do not help, obviously something else needs to be deleted in memory ?? Where do I delete the files I see from in root integrity check? How does this work?

Comment: What "root integrity check" are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Android System Recovery "root integrity check" will check your read-only system partition for modifications. If anything is reported, flash memory is either corrupt or something (or someone) had root access and modified stock ROM intentionally. Your device is therefore compromised/corrupted.

Flash stock ROM from fastboot. In case you want to modify/delete reported files, read back system.img from SP Flash Tool and loop-mount ext4 partition image on linux PC